# Android ProgressDialog not spinning

Tags: android

Progress dialog spinner wheel stops spinning while doing the actual work. How can I make it continually spin the wheel while when my other work is going on.......

```
    progressdialog.setMessage("Please wait. . .");
    progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressdialog.show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadFormView(m_table, m_rLayout, m_param);

                }
            });
           progressdialog.dismiss();
        }

    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `loadFormView` is your "work", that needs to happen on a background thread somehow (thread, intent service, async task, etc).

Right now you're running that "work" on the UI thread, which will block the progress spinning animation.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Here's an example how to use an async task in your case (code is not tested but something along those lines):

```
private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 protected void onPreExecute(){
     progressdialog.show();
 }

 protected void doInBackground(Void params) {
     loadFormView(m_table, m_rLayout, m_param);
     return void;
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     progressdialog.dismiss();
 }

}

//start the task
new LoadTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. Try Doing this way:

```
progressdialog.setMessage("Please wait. . .");
progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressdialog.show();
final Handler h = new Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   public void handleMessage(Message message) {
      progressdialog.dismiss();
      }
   };
Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {  
   public void run() {
     // YOUR WORK
          h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
      }
   }, 1000);
checkUpdate.start();
```

Comment: Sir, I am getting the following error.
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads...

Comment: @Susanta. Try to use a `Handler` and `postDelayed() ` . Check the updated  answer.